# Find the pattern in 1 line and replacing in another line

Tags: vim, vi

I have some local soft link paths of files as below.

```
./tech/finegrain/DUALDFTIO/synopsys/DUALDFTIO.TSMC7N.db
./tech/finegrain/ESD18V/synopsys/ESD18V.TSMC7N.db
```

I got original paths till directories but not the file path . In this case till synopsys as below .

```
/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/DUALDFTIO/0/synopsys

/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/ESD18V/0/synopsys
```

Now I want to get the text after `synopsys` in first set of lines and then append after `synopsys` in second set of lines 
How can I do the above replacement/append  ?

O/p should appear as below .

```
/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/DUALDFTIO/0/synopsys/DUALDFTIO.TSMC7N.db
/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/ESD18V/0/synopsys/ESD18V.TSMC7N.db
```

Comment: I've edited your question to use code formatting. I'm not sure if you meant to have that trailing `.`, so please re-edit as appropriate. You'll also need to provide some more information about the specific strings we're looking for in the document. Are you looking to replace everything after the final `/`? Are you replacing if it matches with a string between the second and third `/`? Does this replacement match to the end of the line? What if there are multiple matches, choose the first? Should we also replace the `f`? Should we select the first replacement in the document or from that line?

Comment: I have edited that **.** .  No I am not trying to replace after final **/** . My intention is to replace all the lines which are having d as last word. d remains same always so I don't have intention to replace always something b/w second  and third **/** . Yes this replacement always end of the line. No there wouldn't be multiple matches.

Comment: For example below tech* are the soft links for few files and proj* are the original files . So I want to replace soft links with original paths , so that if any user deletes soft links , I will not face any problem.

`tech/finegrain/DUALDFTIO/synopsys/DUALDFTIO.TSMC7N.ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL.db \`
`tech/finegrain/GPIO18V/synopsys/GPIO18V.TSMC7N.ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL.db \`


`/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/DUALDFTIO/0/synopsys`
`/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/GPIO18V/0/synopsys`

Comment: Comments are quite hard to read, so please edit your question and add all this information in there. I would clarify the question by adding in a few more lines to the source document(s) that show the range of strings we are to encounter, encompassing those to be processed (the whole variety), and those to be unprocessed (if they exist).

Comment: Sorry as this is pretty long ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL, I have chopped it for more ease in first set of lines but missed in doing output.

Comment: @Swathi Vutukuri your question is not completely clear. The solution below handels the information you provided int he question and can be tweaked pending additional clarifications!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put local soft link paths in a file called `local.txt` and the original paths in a file called `original` then run this command:

```
paste original.txt local.txt | sed 's/synopsys.*synopsys/synopsys/' | sed 's/.db/.ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL.db/'

/proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/DUALDFTIO/0/synopsys/DUALDFTIO.TSMC7N.ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL.db
    /proj/br_ccd_lib/macro/ESD18V/0/synopsys/ESD18V.TSMC7N.ssg.rev1d0u2p2.072v.0c.TSMC7N_1P13M1X1XA1YA5Y2YY2Z1ALRDL.db
```

This solution assume that all the paths in the `local.txt` file end up with `.db` and all paths in local.txt are equivalent to the paths in `original.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer . It's working. What is meant by $NF in the above command ? Is there any possibility to do this with vi search and replace?